# Placement of drawer slides

Tags: drawer

I'm building a small rolling cabinet (36" h x 22" w x 20" d) with inset drawers.  The instructions for the drawer slide extensions direct me to install them at the bottom of the drawers.  Several YouTube videos I've watched have the installer mounting them on the center line of each drawer.  Any pros/cons for either approach?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specific drawer slide.  Some are designed to be mounted at the bottom, some elsewhere.  Follow the instructions of your specific slides.